# upload camera image with angularjs and cordova

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, file-upload, camera

I am working on angularJS web application. When user want to upload image on mobile devices, device should start camera and user can take a picture and upload it.

This is code snippet I am testing

`<input type="file" name="uploadedfile" accept="image/*" capture="camera" />
<input type="file" name="uploadedfile2" accept="image/*" capture />
<input id="myFileInput" type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">`

All three cases are working when testing as web application in phone browser.
But, when I make android application (apk file) using cordova (v6.3.1) I cannot force phone to open camera when user clicks on choose image button. This is my first time using cordova to build apk file from html.

What I am doing wrong?

Update:

Cordova plugins I installed:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-media-capture" spec="~1.4.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="~2.3.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-android-permissions" spec="~0.10.0" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You need device permission to access camera. Following plugins will help:

[cordova-plugin-android-permissions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-android-permissions)

[cordova-plugin-camera](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-camera)